# UIView.animateWithDuration does not work within a UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, animation, cell

I have a `UITableviewCell` subclass that contains a `UIButton` that is placed off-screen (right) with a Autolayout Horizontal Space Constraint to it's superview of -312.

Now I want to animate this constraint to a value of -8 when the the cell is selected.

I have created a outlet for this constraint in the cell class and I tried to animate this constraint with the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VariationsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VariationsCell

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        cell.buttonRightSideConstraint.constant = -8

        }, completion: { finished in
            println("Button revealed!")
    })

}
```

This unfortunately does not work. If I reload the tableview with `.reloadData()` the button is shown, which tells me that that the Autolayout constraint gets updated but the animation does not get triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When animating with auto layout, you have to use `layoutIfNeeded` to animate the changes in the constraints.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VariationsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VariationsCell

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut) {
         cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VariationsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VariationsCell

    cell.buttonRightSideConstraint.constant = -8

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using auto layout on table view cells though. Whenever you call `layoutIfNeeded` in your view controller / table view, your cell's **might** show some unwanted behavior.

Comment: self.layoutIfNeeded results in an error 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'layoutIfNeeded'. Did you mean cell.layoutIfNeeded()? I have tried that already and it does not work.

Comment: Yea sorry, forgot to add that. Also if you're using auto layout in a cell, you should add the subviews to `contentView`.

Comment: I have it all setup as you have suggested. The button was added to the contentView of the TableviewCell in storyboard. The code you are suggesting does not work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, Im half sleeping. You have to add the animation in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Ill update the answer.

Comment: You'll probably need to set up `prepareForReuse()` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is working but I would like to know more about how I should set up my `prepareForReuse()` function?

Comment: From what I've read, you could "reset" the settings to the original state in there. For example, `buttonRightSideConstraint.constant` could be set to `0`, so when you scroll in your table view the cell's will start like in the original state.

Comment: Regarding prepareForReuse: please note that (according to Apple) only "visual" (as opposed to model) reset should be performed in that method. Think opacity/alpha etc

Comment: It works for first time only.. Afterwords it not working with animation